# Program that checks for capitalisation and full stop

Tags: python, regex, string, input, capitalize

I am a beginner programmer. I am trying to write a program that will ask for a sentence, then check for 2 things. 1) A capital letter at the start of the sentence and 2) a full stop at its end. I also want it to print out a sentence that'll tell the user whether or not their sentence is correct.
For example:

**Enter a sentence:** python is hard.

Your sentence doesn't begin with a capital letter.

and

**Enter a sentence:** Python is hard

Your sentence has no full stop at the end.

and

**Enter a sentence:** python is hard

Your sentence doesn't start with a capital letter and has no full stop at the end.

and lastly;

**Enter a sentence:** Python is hard.

Your sentence is perfect.

However, i am stuck and all i have is this mess:

```
sentence = input("Sentence: ")
if sentence[0].isupper():
  print("")
if (sentence[0].isupper()) != sentence:
  print("Your sentence does not start with a capital letter.")
elif "." not in sentence:
  print("Your sentence does not end with a full stop.")
else:
  print("Your sentence is correctly formatted.")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Python is hard.`? Your sentence is wrong... :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sentence = input('Sentence: ') # You should use raw_input if it is python 2.7
if not sentence[0].isupper() and sentence[-1] != '.': # You can check the last character using sentence[-1]
    # both the conditions are not satisfied
    print 'Your sentence does not start with a capital letter and has no full stop at the end.'
elif not sentence[0].isupper():
    # sentence does not start with a capital letter
    print 'Your sentence does not start with a capital letter.'
elif sentence[-1] != '.':
    # sentence does not end with a full stop
    print 'Your sentence does not end with a full stop.'
else:
    # sentence is perfect
    print 'Your sentence is perfect.'
```

Comment: The negation operator in Python is `not` instead of `!`. You're actually getting a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit more modular because you can modify it for various error messages.

```
se = "Python is easy"
errors = []
if not se[0].isupper(): errors.append('does not start with a capital letter')
if se[-1] != '.': errors.append('does not end with a full stop')
if errors != []:
   print('Your sentence ' + ' and '.join(errors) + '.')
else:
   print('Your sentence is perfect.')
```

Comment: Since an empty list will evaluate to `False` in a boolean context, you can actually just write `if errors:`

Answer (score 0):

```
se="Python is easy"
if se[0].isupper() and se[-1]=='.':
   print 'ok'
else:
   print 'Not ok'
```

### Update :

You can use `strip` function to remove unnecessary white space at the start and end of string.

```
se="Python is hard."
se=se.strip()
if se[0].isupper():
    if se[-1]=='.':
        print 'Your sentence is correctly formatted.'
    else:
        print 'Your sentence has no full stop at the end.'
elif se[0].islower() and se[-1]!='.':
    print 'Your sentence doesnt start with a capital letter and has no full stop at the end.'
else:
    print 'Your sentence does not start with a capital letter.'
```

Comment: That is not the desired output.